# Calling a function within the parameter of while loop in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, while-loop

I've been stuck on this concept for about 5 hours now, and it's really frustrating me.

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT col FROM table");
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['data'];
}
```

I understand that the function only fetches one row at a time, but I don't understand how it's being called when the loop resets. How is it being called in `$row = $result->fetch_assoc`? Also, how does this condition evaluate to true if `$row` is null?

Comment: What do you mean by *"when the loop resets"*? A `while` loop does not reset. Also what do you mean by *"how does this condition evaluate to true if `$row` is null?"*? Because if `$row` is `NULL` it does not evaluate to `true`, so you should perhaps define what the *condition* is you ask about.

Comment: And also I'd like to know which parts of the PHP manual have you looked into to get more understanding of this issue. It should be explained and if you got problems to navigate it, you perhaps needs some help with that.

Comment: you must print_r($row) to see its structure

Comment: I realized that the $row variable was set in the while statement, so $row isn't actually null

Answer (score 1):

Okay here is simple test for you,

let have an `array` which has value which is `null` as demonstrated below,

```
$row = array('value' => null);
```

and now lets check for that using `if` condition

```
if($row)
{
    echo "null is making variable value to true so condition will work.";
}
```

paste `code` and `run` it i am sure that you will see message inside of `if` condition.

**Your Condition**

You are using `$result->fetch_assoc()` so as you know it will return `array` which might have `null` value as demonstrated in above example.

but as you see it will return `true` for the `$result` because `$result` actually has value assigned and it is `true`.

**so condition will be satisfied.**

Answer (score 1):

In short the while loop condition is looking for `true`:

```
while(true){
//do this
}
```

So until this expression `$row = $result->fetch_assoc()`  resolves to `true` the while loop will continue.

The question is when it will be not true? when all rows retrieved.

Comment: That is really what it is, simple as that

Answer (score 0):

> how does this condition evaluate to true if $row is null?

It doesn't. That's the point.

Answer (score 0):

Given your code:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['data'];
}
```

The loop condition can be rewritten to the following equivalent:

```
while (($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) != false) {
    echo $row['data'];
}
```

In other words, while `$row` is not falsy, it will continue the loop; `null` is also considered falsy.

Answer (score -1):

the following explanation to your code may help you

```
// run the query. this returns a mysqli_result object on success.
// on failure query function returns false and you have to handle this condition.
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT col FROM table");

// fetch_assoc() here you fetch one row at a time from the mysqli_result
// object into $row. this also moves the pointer to the next row
// so the next call returns the next row.
// This returns false when there is no more rows and exit your while loop
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['data'];
}
```

links you may want to refer
http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: the downvoter!! can you explain what is wrong with the answer?